# Why does this time out? Is the time complexity not O(n^2logn)?

Tags: c++, math, search, time-complexity

This problem comes from a leetcode problem called "3sum." I will include the problem statement, as it might be helpful in answering my questions.

**Problem Statement: Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero. The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.**

I am getting time limit exceeded on the leetcode platform, but I have noticed several other O(n^2logn) solutions being accepted. Am I correct in believing that the time complexity of my solutions is O(n^2logn)? Is my binary search implemented correctly? The only guess I have to as to what is causing my solution to time out, when other similarly implemented O(n^2logn) solutions are accepted, is some sort of error in my binary search loop.

Please help me get to the bottom of this. I have posted the code below.

NOTE: my code times out on a test case consisting of all 0's but is good for the other ones

```
class Solution {
 public:
  vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

    vector<vector<int>> ans;

    vector<vector<int>> ans2;

    unordered_set<string> myset;

    unordered_set<string>::iterator itr;

    int L, M, R, target, temp;

    string s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size()-2; i++)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++) {
        L = j + 1;
        R = nums.size() - 1;
        target = (nums[i] + nums[j]) * -1;

        while (R >= L) {
          M = L + (R - L) / 2;

          if (nums[M] == target) {
            ans.push_back({nums[i], nums[j], nums[M]});
          }

          if (nums[M] >= target) {
            R = M - 1;
          } else {
            L = M + 1;
          }
        }
      }

    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
      s = to_string(ans[i][0]) + to_string(ans[i][1]) + to_string(ans[i][2]);

      itr = myset.find(s);

      if (itr == myset.end()) {
        ans2.push_back(ans[i]);
        myset.insert(s);
      }
    }

    return ans2;
  }
};
```

Comment: `i<nums.size() or nums[i]<0` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds, once `i == nums.size()` .  Basically, your loop walks off the end of `nums` vector.

Comment: You forgot to mention your array being ordered. If not the complexity becomes O(n^3).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. that is surely not the reason

Comment: What makes you sure this is not the reason?

Comment: I still time out on the last test case if I change my first for loop to i<nums.size()-2

Comment: so, @IgorTandetnik , while your observsation is correct and I do need to change my looping condition, it is not the reason for TLE. What I am mainly interested in receiving now and information on the time complexity. I am convinced that it is worst case O(n^2logn) but I am worried I am missing something

Answer (score 3):

I guess your bug is explained in the first comment or it would probably get stuck in the Binary Search while loop.

This'll pass through:

```
// This block might trivially optimize the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::int_fast32_t;
    static const std::vector<std::vector<int>> threeSum(
            std::vector<int>& nums
    ) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> triplets;

        std::sort(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums));

        for (auto index = 0; index < std::size(nums); index++) {
            const SizeType target = -nums[index];
            SizeType lo = index + 1;
            SizeType hi = nums.size() - 1;

            if (target < 0) {
                break;
            }

            while (lo < hi) {
                const SizeType sum = nums[lo] + nums[hi];

                if (sum < target) {
                    lo++;

                } else if (sum > target) {
                    hi--;

                } else {
                    std::vector<int> triplet(3, 0);
                    triplet[0] = nums[index];
                    triplet[1] = nums[lo];
                    triplet[2] = nums[hi];
                    triplets.emplace_back(triplet);

                    while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == triplet[1]) {
                        lo++;
                    }

                    while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == triplet[2]) {
                        hi--;
                    }
                }
            }

            while (index + 1 < std::size(nums) && nums[index + 1] == nums[index]) {
                index++;
            }
        }

        return triplets;
    }
};
```

---

Here are some more efficient Solutions by LeetCode:

- Similar to yours:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(begin(nums), end(nums));
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() && nums[i] <= 0; ++i)
            if (i == 0 || nums[i - 1] != nums[i]) {
                twoSumII(nums, i, res);
            }
        return res;
    }
    void twoSumII(vector<int>& nums, int i, vector<vector<int>> &res) {
        int lo = i + 1, hi = nums.size() - 1;
        while (lo < hi) {
            int sum = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi];
            if (sum < 0) {
                ++lo;
            } else if (sum > 0) {
                --hi;
            } else {
                res.push_back({ nums[i], nums[lo++], nums[hi--] });
                while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == nums[lo - 1])
                    ++lo;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

- Using twoSum helper:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(begin(nums), end(nums));
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() && nums[i] <= 0; ++i)
            if (i == 0 || nums[i - 1] != nums[i]) {
                twoSum(nums, i, res);
            }
        return res;
    }
    void twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int i, vector<vector<int>> &res) {
        unordered_set<int> seen;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); ++j) {
            int complement = -nums[i] - nums[j];
            if (seen.count(complement)) {
                res.push_back({nums[i], complement, nums[j]});
                while (j + 1 < nums.size() && nums[j] == nums[j + 1]) {
                    ++j;
                }
            }
            seen.insert(nums[j]);
        }
    }
};
```

- I guess this would be a better Solution, which doesn't use sorting.
- O(N ^ 2) Time
- O(N) Space

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        set<vector<int>> res;
        unordered_set<int> dups;
        unordered_map<int, int> seen;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
            if (dups.insert(nums[i]).second) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); ++j) {
                    int complement = -nums[i] - nums[j];
                    auto it = seen.find(complement);
                    if (it != end(seen) && it->second == i) {
                        vector<int> triplet = {nums[i], nums[j], complement};
                        sort(begin(triplet), end(triplet));
                        res.insert(triplet);
                    }
                    seen[nums[j]] = i;
                }
            }
        return vector<vector<int>>(begin(res), end(res));
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.